# Mapnik LineSymbolizer for overlaping lines

Tags: line, overlapping-features, mapnik

I'm creating a map with Mapnik, and I have some trouble to correctly render overlapping lines. Fot instance let's consider this piece of XML:

```
<Style name="ferry-routes">
    <Rule>
        &min-zoom-12;
        <LineSymbolizer stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.5" />
        <LineSymbolizer stroke="#0000ff" stroke-dasharray="2, 5" stroke-width="1" />
    </Rule>
</Style>

<Layer maximum-scale-denominator="3000000" name="ferry-routes">

    <StyleName><![CDATA[ferry-routes]]></StyleName>

    <Datasource>
        &postgis-settings;
        <Parameter name="dbname">osm</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="table"><![CDATA[(
            SELECT
                osm_id,
                way
            FROM
                planet_osm_line
            WHERE
                route = 'ferry'
            ) AS ferry_routes]]></Parameter>
    </Datasource>

</Layer>
```

When two lines have the exact same geometry, I'd expect it to draw, in this order:

- white background of line 1
- blue dashes of line 1
- white background of line 2
- blue dashes of line 2

Resulting in only line 2 to be visible.

Instead, it does this:

- white background of line 1
- white background of line 2
- blue dashes of line 1
- blue dashes of line 2

Resulting in all the dashes to be visible, like here (buggy line on the left, correct one on the right):

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in Mapnik, I opened a ticket here: https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/4034

To workaround the issue, I selected only the ferry lines with a positive osm_id.